# Can't use OpenCV GeneralizedHoughTransform class with Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, hough-transform

I'm trying to code a basic example of use of GeneralizedHoughBallard class using OpenCV 4.0.0 and Python 3.6. I have found an example for C++ here https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.0/samples/gpu/generalized_hough.cpp but no for Python.

When I try to create a new instance of GeneralizedHoughBallard class:

```
import cv2
alg = cv2.createGeneralizedHoughBallard()
```

I get the error: "AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'createGeneralizedHoughBallard".

I've seen in the OpenCV source (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.0.0/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp) that createGeneralizedHoughBallard is declared with CV_EXPORTS so I suppose it should be possible to use with Python. I've tried to use another similar function that is declared in the same file (improc.hpp) for example: cv2.createCLAHE() and works fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's called just `GeneralizedHoughBallard`

```py
import cv2
print([x for x in dir(cv2) if 'Hough' in x])
print([x for x in dir(cv2) if x.startswith('create')])
```

```
['GeneralizedHough',
 'GeneralizedHoughBallard',
 'GeneralizedHoughGuil',
 'HoughCircles',
 'HoughLines',
 'HoughLinesP',
 'HoughLinesPointSet']
['createAffineTransformer',
 'createAlignMTB',
 'createBackgroundSubtractorKNN',
 'createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2',
 'createButton',
 'createCLAHE',
 'createCalibrateDebevec',
 'createCalibrateRobertson',
 'createChiHistogramCostExtractor',
 'createEMDHistogramCostExtractor',
 'createEMDL1HistogramCostExtractor',
 'createHanningWindow',
 'createHausdorffDistanceExtractor',
 'createLineSegmentDetector',
 'createMergeDebevec',
 'createMergeMertens',
 'createMergeRobertson',
 'createNormHistogramCostExtractor',
 'createShapeContextDistanceExtractor',
 'createThinPlateSplineShapeTransformer',
 'createTonemap',
 'createTonemapDrago',
 'createTonemapDurand',
 'createTonemapMantiuk',
 'createTonemapReinhard',
 'createTrackbar']
```

Comment: From your answer and this other <http://answers.opencv.org/question/211122/how-to-use-opencv-generalizedhoughtransform-class-with-python/> in opencv forum, I've realized that for expose the function to Python is necesary CV_EXPORTS_W not CV_EXPORTS, and createGeneralizedHoughBallard uses this last one. I think I have to change the code an recompile it. Thanks!